# Clicking on a spoiler tag to reveal the text shouldn't navigate you to another page

Tags: feature-request, spoilers, touch-screen

This is an issue I noticed when reading [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/28206/392). On multiple occasions I ended up inadvertently clicking a link that I could not see when I was just trying to reveal the spoiler text.

> [Never gonna give you up Never gonna let you down Never gonna run
>  around and desert you Never gonna make you cry Never gonna say goodbye
>  Never gonna tell a lie and hurt you](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Can links be deactivated in spoilers until the text is revealed?

(Edit: this issue seems particularly to apply to those using touch screen devices with the "full site" theme)

Comment: You got me... I clicked it!

Comment: You don't have to click to reveal the text, just hover (although you have to click to make it permanent). I guess you might click accidentally, but this could happen even for text not under a spoiler block.

Comment: @sumelic I'm using Safari on an iPad so hovering isn't possible.

Comment: Ah, good point then.

Comment: This should probably have some sort of tag to specify the fact that it relates to touchscreen devices specifically, even if not in mobile view.

Comment: I never knew clicking made it permanently visible until now.

Comment: Technically, when you hover, the text is already revealed and the link is already active. You should ask for a delay.

Comment: Your request is specific to mobile devices, I have edited to reflect this. /cc @Catija

Comment: @ShadowWizard Touchscreen <> mobile. You can get touchscreen desktop monitors. I'm not using the mobile theme on my tablet.

Comment: OK, so please mention it somehow in your question. Personally I do NOT want to have the link disabled in the ordinary desktop theme of the site. I hover the spoiler, see the link, and I want to be able to click it.

Comment: So this request wouldn't affect you then, as the request is that the links should be active when the text is visible. It does not request that the current behaviour of toggling visibility on hover be removed.

Comment: Sorry about the edits... forgot to read the comments :)